# Reset user password

Tags: craft3

User password reset mail is acting weird. When resetting the user password the mail I receive has `forgot_password_subject` subject and `forgot_password_body` content.

I tried checking the source code but after an hour I gave up. I think this might be an issue with the database. I am guessing after few updates of Craft the database got corrupted?

Any ideas if this configuration is stored in any of the database tables?

The reset user password functionality works normally while being accessed via admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "-1" hater, it was actually a bug in the craft, [issue link](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3673).